# Website input type text focus only works when browser loses and gets focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website uses several input text elements and they are defined in HTML like:

```
<input type='text' style='width:200px;'/>
```

However if I open my webpage and I click on these inputs, they look like this:

[image: Text field before the browser loses and gains focus]

So they display with no cursor and no blue border when they are selected.
But if I click outside the chrome browser, for example if I click on my desktop and then back to chrome, the inputs work and look like following:

[image: Text field after the browser loses and gains focus]

So after this step, they look how they are supposed to.

This only happens in chrome and only on the server, all works fine on localhost.

I have no blur functions or anything else. What causes this issue?

Do anyone have any ideas about this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide some code for us to review.

Comment: Hi i will post the whole code below

Comment: You can post it to your original answer, click Edit.

Comment: it says to long